# I don't know where my Ethereum went, or what wallet I created... how can i transfer it to a new wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallets, addresses

Going back a few years I made a purchase that is visible in Etherscan. But I am clueless as to where it went, what I bought or where it is now? All I've realised is that I'm as naieve now as I was then. Would like to get this all back under control, so any help greatly appreciated.
I have 2 public adresses: One for Etherwallet and the other for Idex wallet. I think I had to purchase Ethereum to buy POLY. I've unlocked my IDEX wallet with my private key and there is no record at all.

Comment: Without more concrete information (your wallets addressses) there's nothing to reply to your question. Please elaborate more on your question and provide more information

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My public address for Etherwallet is: 0x3780f56e17803518ba66ec5e645a8Ea1Dabd2e89

Comment: And the Idex wallet address is: 0x4ad0fb0672cbb9ef788a134522b0caefaa9dbb7f, this is the address that Ethereum was sent to on 14/2/2018, does that help?

Comment: Are you in the control of `0x4ad0fb0672cbb9ef788a134522b0caefaa9dbb7f` ? Don't know about the first address you sent, but from the latter one there's a deposit to a DEX contract at `0x2a0c0DBEcC7E4D658f48E01e3fA353F44050c208` which you should be able to withdraw without a problem

Comment: Yes I am in control of that address but when I log in there is no record of any transaction, nothing shows at all, so I'm not seeing any record or history.

Answer (score 3):

I checked your 0x3780f56e17803518ba66ec5e645a8Ea1Dabd2e89 wallet and while no transactions shows up on etherscan it says you have 197 poly or 91 dollars so import your 0x3780f56e17803518ba66ec5e645a8Ea1Dabd2e89 wallet into metamask and then click import token [image: ad shown here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRGDc.png) after that import this token address as it is the poly address 0x9992ec3cf6a55b00978cddf2b27bc6882d88d1ec [image: like this] and click add custom token and you should be ready to go

as for the other wallet address, it should be the same steps but it says you only have 3 cents worth of poly and when I call the contract function of Idex balanceOf and input 0x4ad0fb0672cbb9ef788a134522b0caefaa9dbb7f and input the poly token address it says you have 0 poly in their contract so I'm not really sure about that wallet hope this helps best of luck